# Start Automated Python Program Using Venv with a Shell Script

Tags: python-3.x, bash, python-venv

I want to automate a Python program that uses a virtual environment. In order to do that, I need to launch the Python virtual environment first. I am able to do this by hand on the command line. However, when I put the command in a shell script so that it will execute at a certain time with the "at" command, I get the following error:

```
run.sh: 7: source: not found
```

Here is the shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Path to your virtual environment activate script
VENV_PATH="/home/user/python/app/venv/bin/activate"

# Activate the virtual environment
source "$VENV_PATH"

# Run your Python program
python3 /home/user/python/app/main.py
```

What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: can you run the *script* from the command line? please update the question with the complete `at` command

Comment: You don't need to activate a python virtualenv to use it, that's primarily for interactive shells. Explicitly calling the venv's python should work eg `/home/user/python/app/venv/bin/python3 /home/user/python/app/main.py` should work without activation.

Comment: The specific error you got indicates you ran that bash script with `sh` instead of `bash`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your /home/user/python/app/main.py and add shebang as first line

```
#! /home/user/python/app/venv/bin/python3
...
```

then

```
chmod +x /home/user/python/app/main.py
```

and you can just execute `main.py` (you could remove the file extension too)